# xgboost library 0.9 vs 1.3.3

Tags: xgboost, backwards-compatibility

I worked for some time on hyper-parameters tuning on a XGBRegressor based on xgboost library version 0.9 (Python for Anaconda on Windows).
After installing the latest Anaconda and xgboost(version 1.3.3 this time) on a different PC, I noticed different results on the same code. Here is the simplified code:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
params = {
    'max_depth': 9,
    'n_estimators': 400,
    'learning_rate': 0.1,
    'min_child_weight': 2,
    'reg_alpha': 0.05,
    'reg_lambda': 1,
    'colsample_bytree': .8,
    'colsample_bynode': 1,
    'colsample_bylevel': .9,
    'objective': 'reg:squarederror'

}

model = XGBRegressor(**params)
model.fit(X, Y)
```

If I am using model to make predictions, I get different results with xgb 1.3.3. I tried to match the hyper parameters by adding all the new default parameters I found in the 1.3.3 library

```
'base_score': 0.5,
'booster': 'gbtree',
'gamma': 0,
'max_delta_step': 0,
'random_state': 0,
'scale_pos_weight': 1,
'subsample': 1,
'seed': 0
```

but still the same result. Can you help me adapting the code in order to get the same results on the new environment. I need this to avoid reworking on tuning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which version of XGboost have you used for the desired results. If it `xgboost 0.9`, you need to install this version. To do so, first uninstall xgboost

```
pip uninstall xgboost
```

and then, install xgboost-0.9

```
pip install xgboost==0.9
```

You can also look for updates [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/6825/files)

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your feedback but this is not what I intend to do. I want to be able to migrate my code from xgboost 0.9 to 1.3.3 while preserving the output.
I suppose I have to add some explicit parameter values for the new constructor and fit method.

Comment: You should look the link I've provided in the answer for the updates, and see what they have changed in the parameters defaults or even have added new parameters.